# Item selection not working on Android tablet

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, listview

I have a Java for Android app that works fine in my Eclipse emulator, but when I install it on a tablet, it stops working. The tablet is running OS 4.04 and it's a Galaxy tablet 10.1. When I run my app on the tablet, I see my initial 3 choices: Beginning, Intermediate and Advanced. But when I touch one of the choices, the screen goes blank and I can't use the Back button to get back to my initial screen. My manifest has:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
```

Here's my code from my onCreate() method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    PopulateDatabase();        
    ListView listview = getListView();
    final String[] values = new String[] {
            "Beginning", "Intermediate", "Advanced"
    };

    StitchArrayAdapter adapter = new StitchArrayAdapter(this, values);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    listview.setSelector(R.drawable.stitchlist_selector);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            Intent choice = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.MyKnitCards.project.StitchList.class);
            Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
            String chosenValue = values[position];
            dataBundle.putString("Level",chosenValue);
            choice.putExtras(dataBundle);
            try {
                startActivity(choice);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Dialog d = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
                d.setTitle("MyKnitCardsActivity line 60");
                TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                tv.setText(e.toString());
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            } finally {

            }
        }

    });
}
```

My stitchlist_selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<!-- Selected --> 
<item 
android:state_focused="true" 
android:state_selected="false" 
android:drawable="@drawable/focused"/> 
<!-- Pressed -->
<item 
android:state_selected="true" 
android:state_focused="false"
android:drawable="@drawable/selected" />
```

My StitchList class:

```
package com.MyKnitCards.project;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;

public class StitchList extends FragmentActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.stitchfragment);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    //DetailFrag frag = new DetailFrag();
    DetailFrag frag = (DetailFrag) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_stitchdetail);
    frag.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    return false;
}
```

}

And here's my stitchfragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<fragment android:id="@+id/frag_stitchlist"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
class="com.MyKnitCards.project.ListFrag" />
<fragment android:id="@+id/frag_stitchdetail"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.MyKnitCards.project.DetailFrag" />
```

My logcat:

```
01-07 17:28:56.419: D/dalvikvm(533): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
01-07 17:28:56.999: I/ActivityThread(533): Pub com.MyKnitCards.project.StitchProvider: com.MyKnitCards.project.StitchProvider
01-07 17:28:57.099: I/dalvikvm(533): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-07 17:28:57.109: I/dalvikvm(533): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-07 17:28:57.579: D/gralloc_goldfish(533): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
01-07 17:28:57.599: I/dalvikvm(533): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
01-07 17:28:57.609: I/dalvikvm(533): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

I'm pretty much a Java/Android noob, so I apologize if the answer is obvious, but I just don't see a problem. I also don't get an error message on the tablet, so I don't know where to even start looking.

---

Addition on 1/9/2014:

I realized there's a piece of code I didn't include. When the `setContentView()`is called in the StitchList class, it goes to my ListFrag class:

```
private static final String STITCHTABLE_BASEPATH = "MyStitches_tbl";
private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.MyKnitCards.project.StitchProvider";
public static final Uri STITCHES_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/" + STITCHTABLE_BASEPATH);
private static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] { "_id", "stitchname", "stitchuses", "videopath", "stitchinstructions", "stitchnotes", "stitchlevel" };
private SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;   
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    Intent myData = getActivity().getIntent();
    Bundle info = myData.getExtras();

    String[] dataColumns = { "stitchname" };
    int[] viewIDs = { R.id.stitchlist1 };
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.stitchlist, null, dataColumns, viewIDs, 0);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, info, (LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>) this); 
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Cursor c = ((SimpleCursorAdapter)l.getAdapter()).getCursor();
    c.moveToPosition(position);
    int stitchid = c.getInt(0);
    String stitchname = c.getString(1);
    String stitchuses = c.getString(2);
    String videopath = c.getString(3);
    String stitchinstructions = c.getString(4);
    String stitchnotes = c.getString(5);
    String stitchlevel = c.getString(6);

    DetailFrag frag = (DetailFrag) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_stitchdetail);
    if (frag != null && frag.isInLayout()) {
        frag.setText(stitchname, R.id.stitchname);
        frag.setText(stitchuses, R.id.stitchuses);
        frag.setText(stitchinstructions, R.id.stitchinstructions);
        frag.setText(stitchnotes, R.id.stitchnotes);
        frag.setVideo(videopath, stitchlevel);
        frag.setRowID(stitchid);
        EditText notes = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.stitchnotes);
        notes.setVisibility(0);
        ImageButton savebutton = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.savebutton);
        savebutton.setVisibility(0);        }
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String selection = "stitchlevel=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {args.getString("Level")};
    return (Loader<Cursor>) new CursorLoader(getActivity(), STITCHES_URI,
            PROJECTION, selection, selectionArgs, null);    
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {          mAdapter.swapCursor((android.database.Cursor) cursor);      
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);

}
```

Is there a clue here as to what's breaking? I found [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html) describing how to debug an app on a device, but just like in the emulator, the program never seems to break. I get no error messages on the screen or in LogCat, but after I choose Beginning, Intermediate or Advanced, the screen just shows my background color (a very nice green), but no list of stitches. Very perplexed.

Comment: In the onCreate() of your First Activity, where do you call `setContentView()`?

Comment: See my onItemClick method in my first activity and then follow that to the onCreate() method of my StitchList class. The setContentView() is there.

Comment: That is very much the wrong way to be using that. That should be called immediately in onCreate(). Do you have a LogCat output?

Comment: Please put in in your original question so it is properly formatted. Also, when you try to catch your exception, you never print it out. Why not? That could be valuable information.

Comment: My logcat is now in the original question. I think I am printing out my exception (see my code in the catch block), but as I said, nothing shows on the screen.

Comment: You're right, you were, I was just looking for something that would show up in LogCat. That's how exceptions are normally logged. Is that the extent of your LogCat?

Comment: Yes, that's all that's there.

Comment: OK, this is embarrassing. I figured out the answer and it's that I'm an idiot. In my defense, I hadn't looked at this app in months, but here's what was going on: I'd commented out all the code that populated the database that I was pulling to populate my lists. I have no idea why I would've done that, and it was working in the emulator because I'd run the app at some point when the code wasn't commented out, but that was the fix. Very sorry for wasting everyone's time!